# Bromwich integral transformed to an integral on the real axis

Tags: cv.complex-variables, laplace-transform

I am new in complex integration and inverse Laplace transforms. I already asked this question on math.se but got no answer.

The author of a textbook claims that the inverse Laplace transform has expression
$$
f(t) = \frac{2\exp(bt)}{\pi}\int_0^\infty\Re\bigl(\hat{f}(b+iu)\bigr)\cos(ut)\,\mathrm{d}u.
$$
He obtains this formula by substituting $s = b+iu$ in the Bromwich integral
$$
f(t) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{b-i\infty}^{b+i\infty}\exp(st)\hat{f}(s)\,\mathrm{d}s.
$$
However I've numerically checked this formula and it doesn't seem to hold true:

```
fhat <- function(s) 1/(s+3) # Laplace transform of exp(-3x)
b <- 5 
integrand <- function(u, x){
  Re(fhat(b+1i*u))*cos(x*u)
}
x <- 2 
2*exp(b*x)/pi * integrate(integrand, 0, Inf, x = x, subdivisions = 10000)$value
# -0.1124648
exp(-3*x)
# 0.002478752
```

For $b = -2$ the result is close to the expected value $\exp(-3x)$:

```
b <- -2
2*exp(b*x)/pi * integrate(integrand, 0, Inf, x = x, subdivisions = 10000)$value
# 0.002479138
```

I understood that $b$ must be choosen anywhere at the right of the singularities of $\hat{f}$ (here $-3$). Am I wrong? Here the result depends on the choice of $b$. Do I misunderstand something, or is there something wrong in this textbook?

Here is the derivation of the formula:

[image]

Comment: This does seem weird - if I just do the substitution, I get $(\mbox{Re} \hat{f}) \cos ut - (\mbox{Im} \hat{f}) \sin ut $ instead of $2 (\mbox{Re} \hat{f}) \cos ut$ ... maybe some additional assumptions are made about $\hat{f} $?

Comment: @MichaelEngelhardt I just edited my post to add the derivation of the formula.

Comment: Also [here](http://web.ist.utl.pt/~ist12219/data/95.pdf), equation (12).

Comment: Ah yes, that was the decisive additional ingredient, that $f$ vanishes for $t<0$ - this makes the terms with $\mbox{Re} \hat{f} $ and $\mbox{Im} \hat{f} $ equal. So, it seems to me that the derivation in the book is fine as long as $\hat{f} $ is sufficiently well-behaved for the integrals to exist. I would rather be sceptical of the numerical evaluation - have you varied the step size? That "subdivisions" variable doesn't seem very large ... and you have oscillatory integrands ...

Comment: @MichaelEngelhardt You're right, this is a numerical problem. I've tried with [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=exp%285%29+*+%28integral+of+%28cos%28u%29+*+real+part+of+%281%2F%285%2BI*u+%2B+3%29%29%29+for+u+from+0+to+infinity%29) and the value indeed does not depend on $b$. Changing `subdiv` in R has no effect.

Comment: Interesting, and a cautionary tale - good to hear you gained further insight.

Comment: @MichaelEngelhardt Yes, and this book does not mention the difficulty to numerically evaluate such an integral. That's not serious. I've tried a more powerful numerical integration routine in R and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment:

The following paper give a review of existing inverse Lapplace transform algorithms:

Kristopher L. Kuhlman, "Review of inverse Laplace transform algorithms
for Laplace-space numerical approaches", Numerical Algorithms 63, No. 2, pp. 339-355 (2013),  [DOI 10.1007/s11075-012-9625-3](https://doi.org/10.1007/s11075-012-9625-3), [MR3057203](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR3057203), [Zbl 1269.65134](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A1269.65134).

and a little bit more specific

Lloyd N. Trefethen, J. André C. Weideman, and Thomas Schmelzer, "Talbot quadratures and rational approximations", BIT Numerical Mathematics, 46(3), pp. 653-670 (2006), [DOI 10.1007/s10543-006-0077-9](https://doi.org/10.1007/s10543-006-0077-9), [MR2265580](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR2265580), [Zbl 1103.65030](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A1103.65030).

Of course they do not mention your specific implementation of the Bromwich inversion integral.

Fernando Damian Nieuwveldt has implemented in [this code](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576934/) a fine version of the inverse Laplace algorithm (in Python, not in R). Here an excerpt:

Talbot suggested that the Bromwich line be deformed into a contour that begins and ends in the left half plane, i.e., $z \to −\infty$ at both ends.

Due to the exponential factor the integrand decays rapidly on such a contour. In such situations the trapezoidal rule converge extraordinarily rapidly.
For example (in Nieuwveldt's code) here we compute the inverse transform of $F(s) = 1/(s+1)$ at $t = 1$.

If you are interested in more precision you find an algorithm with arbitrary precision in [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576938-numerical-inversion-of-the-laplace-transform-with-/).